# Proposition $4.3$ of Chapter $8$ of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I never did a course on algebraic topology, so I would like to a reference to understand why $p$ is a regular covering and why this implies $p(\tilde{x}) = p(\tilde{y})$ if and only if $\Gamma \tilde{x} = \Gamma \tilde {y}$ in the proof below

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To understand universal coverings, totally discontinuous groups, regular coverings, etc., you don't need very much algebraic topology, just the fundamental group and the theory of covering spaces. You ought to be able to find those topics in more elementary topology books; I recommend Munkres' book "Topology".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood why $p$ is a regular covering and why this implies $p(\tilde{x}) = p(\tilde{y})$ if and only if $\Gamma \tilde{x} = \Gamma \tilde {y}$.

I will answer considering that the people that will see this answer didn't a course in algebraic topology like me.

First of all, regular covering is also known as *normal covering* in the literature.

Let $\mathcal{C}_p(\tilde{X})$ denote the set of all covering transformations of $\tilde{X}$ with respect to $p$.

The proposition below answer why $p(\tilde{x}) = p(\tilde{y})$ if and only if $\Gamma \tilde{x} = \Gamma \tilde {y}$ once that $p$ is a regular covering:

> $\textbf{Proposition $11.29$ (Orbit Criterion).}$ Let $p: \tilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be a covering map.
>
> (b) $\mathcal{C}_p(\tilde{X})$ acts transitively on each fiber if and only if $p$ is a normal covering.

A proof of this result can be found in 'Introduction to Topological Manifolds' by John Lee.

Observing that $\tilde{M}$ is simply connected in the proposition $4.3$ because $\tilde{M} = S^n, \mathbb{R}^n$ or $H^n$ by hypothesis, $\mathcal{C}_p(\tilde{X}) \cong \pi_1(X,q)$, where $q = p(\tilde{q})$ (see corollary $11.32$ of John Lee's book). Then $p$ be a regular covering is a consequence from the fact that every connected manifold is path-connected and from the result below

> Suppose $p: Y \longrightarrow X$ is a covering space with $X$ path-connected, and let $G = \pi_1(X, x_0)$. Then, the $G$–set $M = p^{−1}(x_0)$ is transitive if and only if $Y$ is path-connected.

See Lemma $0.57$ of [this](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Ehensel/teaching/19top/19-top-script.pdf) lecture notes for a proof.